# Subtract one day from datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query to fetch date diff between 2 datetime as :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @CreatedDate , GETDATE())

Ex :

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2013-03-13 00:00:00.000' , GETDATE())
```

I need to have a query work like this which will subtract a day from created day:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, **@CreatedDate- 1** , GETDATE())
```

Comment: Why not just add 1 to the result?

Comment: If *subtracting* 1 from the result is giving the desired answer, then the question you've posed seems wrong, since *subtracting* from the result is equivalent to *adding* a number of days onto the earlier of the dates.

Comment: Then the expression you posted as your first reply to me is the one that I'd use - you could post it as an answer, but as I say, it means that your question isn't really correct (the `DATEDIFF` between `2003-03-12` and today is 14, not 12).

Comment: Yes..you are right..it works like the opposite with the results..

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, '2013-03-13 00:00:00.000'), GETDATE())
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, @CreatedDate), GETDATE())
```

Comment: Following the answer from Philip Rego, you can use SELECT GETDATE() - 1 to subtract days from a date.

Comment: Be slightly careful with the minus 1.  As long as everyone knows that it only works on DateTime.  It does NOT work on Date data types.  CAST(GetDate() - 1 AS DATE) /* works */, CAST(GetDate() AS DATE) - 1 /* error */

Answer (score 62):

I am not certain about what precisely you are trying to do, but I think this SQL function will help you:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,'2013-04-01 16:25:00.250')
```

The above will give you `2013-03-31 16:25:00.250`.

It takes you back exactly one day and works on any standard date-time or date format.

Try running this command and see if it gives you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,@CreatedDate)
```

Answer (score 58):

To simply subtract one day from todays date:

```
Select DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
```

(original post used -7 and was incorrect)

Answer (score 40):

Apparently you can subtract the number of days you want from a datetime.

```
SELECT GETDATE() - 1

2016-12-25 15:24:50.403
```

Comment: Postgres equivalent would be `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 1` or `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INT '1'`. More [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 12):

This should work.

```
select DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (
    DAY, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, @CreatedDate, -1), 
    GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may this will help you

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY,-1,'2013-03-13 00:00:00.000') , GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I just use:

```
select convert(nvarchar(max), GETDATE(), 112)
```

which gives `YYYYMMDD` and minus one from it.

Or more correctly

```
select convert(nvarchar(max), GETDATE(), 112) - 1
```

for yesterdays date.

Replace `Getdate()` with your value `OrderDate`

```
select convert(nvarchar (max),OrderDate,112)-1 AS SubtractDate FROM Orders
```

should do it.

Comment: It doesn't work if any cases, for example if you replace the getdate() by '2022-11-01 10:00:00.000' your result will be '20221100'  instead of '20221031'

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky.I have faced problems with this myself. Note that if you are trying to use this in your `where` clause or on your `join` condition, then without converting the field to a `date` field from a `datetime`, it might not fetch you any results. For example, the code snippet below doesn't give no results, even though the query at a surface level looks alright.

```
SELECT 
PatientID,
count(1) AS Total_Count
FROM EmergencyDepart_Data ED_Data
WHERE ED_Data.[Arrival Date] = getdate() - 1
GROUP BY PatientID
```

Where as the below query fetches desired results in my case when converted into `date` from `datetime` field. Here is the same code with conversion.

```
SELECT 
PatientID,
COUNT(1) AS Total_Count
FROM EmergencyDepart_Data ED_Data
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ED_Data.[Arrival Date]) = CONVERT(DATE, GetDate() - 1)
GROUP BY PatientID
```

When I ran both queries is that there is no `date` that evaluates to the comparison in the `where` clause in the first query, therefore, the second query gives results when used after converting to `date` from `datetime` as it matches with the `date` that is available in the database.

For more clarity, try running the following queries.

```
select getdate() as Today_Date
select convert(date, getdate()) as Converted_Date
```

or

```
select getdate()-1 as Yesterday_date, getdate() as TodayDate
select convert(date, getdate()-1) Converted_Date
```

Now, clearly we won't have any record that matches with the time that the where clause evaluates to within the table.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this.

**Timestamp=2008-11-11 13:23:44.657;**

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(OrderDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS SubtractDate FROM Orders
```

**output :2008-11-10 13:23:44.657**

I hope, it will help to solve your problem.

Comment: SQL Server. Doesn't support `INTERVAL` or `DATE_SUB`.

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(day,45,OrderDate) FROM Orders. You got it?